# PHP/PDO strange request

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, database-connection

I want to do a PDO request that will get informations from 2 different tables, but things fastly get hard, i explain :

I have a first database table (flowers) that is organized like this (but it's REALLY bigger than what I show to you) :

```
ID;       name;              price of format 1; price of format 2; name of other format 3; price of other format 3;
FLOW0001; big yellow flower; ;                  15,99;             more big format;        34,99; 
FLOW0002; little red flower; 5,99;              8,99;              ;                       ;
```

... it goes on like this...

The second table (trees) is like this :

```
ID;       name;            name of format;  price of format;
TREE0001; OMG BIG TREE !;  F*** big format; 599,99; 
TREE0001; OMG BIG TREE !;  F*** even bigger format; 899,99; 
TREE0002; litte ugly tree; little format;   20,99;
```

... it goes on like this...

The thing is that I want to "merge" these 2 tables and to show them togheter blended in a page like this :

```
while ($datas =$response->fetch()) //fetching the tables, they will be togheter and ordered by (their biggest) price. So, trees and flowers will blend. 
{
    // then echo the fetched datas. I will need to separate the prices and show them... some if/else based on pregmatches of the ID to know if it's an TREE or FLOW. 
}
```

How to blend this ? Igot no Ideas. The worst is that I will need to do a page system (50 per pages). On the page system and in the pages, all the duplicated trees will need to appear as only uniques trees... HELP !

Comment: You should reconsider your design approach. You should not have many columns in a table that have the same role (such as `person_1`, `person_2`, `person_3`), in stead you should have a separate `person` table that you can join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `union` to get the data from both tables. just be sure that you are returning matching columns in both queries. So if in your first query you have the following data types `int, text, varchar, decimal, decimal` you will need to make sure that the second query gets those same column types otherwise the DB will have a hissyfit about it. You can use an order by clause on the end to sort the data from both queries nicely.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
select
    ID,
    name,
    price
from
    flowers
where
    // your clauses
union   
select
    ID,
    name,
    price
from
    trees
where
    // your clauses
order by 3 desc
```

Edit: You can `group_concat()` fields in them if you want, and yes, you will be able to do an `explode()` on them in your PHP. The default group_concat delimiter is a , (comma) so if you have commas in your fields, you will need to change it to something so that your explode works nicely.

Comment: can I group concat the price of the second one ?

Comment: Also, if I will explode the group concat, will it gives me an normal numbered array that I can count ?

Comment: An explode will always return a numbered array, and you can union two select statements if they return the same amount of columns, I'm not aware of any other requirements.